# Why do the limits in multi variable integrals have to be in increasing order of variables.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Why is it that in multivariable integration, the limits have to be in this order: $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}\displaystyle \int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)}\displaystyle \int_{h_1(x,y)}^{h_2(x,y))}f(x,y,z)dzdydx$. Why is it that $g_1,g_2$ have to be functions of only $x$ and $h_1,h_2$ have to be functions of $x,y$. Why can't $g_1$ be a function of $x,y$ for instance? In other words, why is the order important here when it is not when we are integrating over a regular rectangular block.

Answer (score 0):

How would you make sense of
$$
    \int_{2x}^{3x^2} \sin(x)\,dx?
$$
The variable in the integral is a “dummy” variable while the variable in the limits is not.  So this expression does not compute.

By the same token, we cannot evaluate an integral like
$$
    \int_{x-y}^{x+3y} \sin(xy)\,dy
$$
because the same variable $y$ is both integrated over and in the limits.

So in each of the iterated integrals, the limits of integration can only be functions of the variables that haven't been integrated over yet.  In the innermost integral $\int_{h_1(x,y)}^{h_2(x,y)} f(x,y,z)\,dz$, we integrate over $z$ between two functions of $x$ and $y$.  That results in some function $F(x,y)$.  The next integral is $\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)} F(x,y)\,dy$, so we integrate with respect to $y$ between limits that depend on $x$.  The result is a function $G(x)$ of $x$ alone.  We integrate *that* between two limits which are functions of *no* variables—i.e., constants.